# Сборка в CMake и Poco lib

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2017, cmake, poco

Для компиляции обычного проекта, я закидывал нужные dll из Poco в папку проекта. Как мне сейчас при сборке проекта уже в CMake, связать папку с dll (как я понимаю что-то нужно добавить в CMakeLists.txt), чтобы работа программы не падала из-за ошибки поиска нужных dll. Спасибо за помощь

Comment: На сколько я знаю poco генерирует файлы проекта с помощью .bat а потом файл проекта запускается в IDE и компилируется lib. У вас какое IDE ?

Comment: Вы можете точно так же руками всё копировать, можно конечно этот шаг в Cmake добавить, но, вообще говоря, если уж для тестов это используется на машине разработчика, то всё необходимые Dll должны быть в $Path

Comment: @ЮрійПисанка, указывал в тэгах - VS2017

Comment: @ixSci, хотелось бы чтобы после сборки проекта в cmake, не выбивало ошибок про dll при запуске в студии, и чтобы не приходилось постоянно в свойствах проекта копаться. возможно ли это вообще?

Comment: @ArturBondar, добавьте путь к dll Poco в Path Windows. Это самый нормальный путь для машины разработчика.